# Multi Line in Gridview Databound Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with some columns among them is address column

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="baddress" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression = "baddress" />
```

I populate my gridview with a datasource at the backend code like

```
Gridview1.DataSource = datasouce;
```

Howver,  the address column is too wide as it display the whole address as returned from db in a single row. Please how do i fix the address column size and make it in to multiple lines. I saw similar examples but they all seem to suggest the use of ItemTemplate (i.e Labe/TextBox). Please any help would be appreciated. Note, my gridview is sorting, paging and all implemented in the backend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template field and set the style for `word-wrap`,

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="350px" HeaderText="Address">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 350px;word-wrap:break-word; ">
            <%# Eval("baddress")%>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank you Your answer really helped. However i had to            `<div style="width: 350px;word-wrap:break-word; ">` To `<div style="width: 350px;white-space: pre-wrap; >`. `word-wrap:break-word` was not identified. Also i revert back the changes for it looks ugly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using ItemStyle-Width on your Boundfield should work, see here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1344016.aspx?How+do+I+fix+the+gridview+column+width+

Alternatively, did you ever consider using an icon to represent the address? When hovering over the icon a tooltip could show which displays the address.